# Cannot change the depth in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, counters, abntex2

I cannot remove subsections from the contents. When I compile the following example:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Show sections
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{char}
\section{Sec}
\subsection{Subsec}
```

, the table of contents is:

```
1 ........ char
1.1 ...... Sec
1.1.1 .... Subsec
```

I have also changed `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` to 0 and placed it before `\begin{document}` or after `\tableofcontents`, but the subsection is always listed.

A working example:

```
\documentclass[
    english
    ]{abntex2}
    
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % up to sections
%\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{char}
\section{Sec}
\subsection{Subsec}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper MWE.

Comment: What you have shown should work so you have done something that you havn't shown us. Please provide and MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that shows your problem.

Comment: This happens because the `tocdepth` of the class is set to 5. The class is intended to follow the `ABNT` rules, and you cannot have numbered sections that do not go to the toc, according to the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to write the change to the ToC at the beginning of your document, since there is some other component of [`abntex2`](//ctan.org/pkg/abntex2) (or its subsidiary loads) that adds an override to the ToC.

[image]

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\changetocdepth{1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```